# What are the specific breakpoint sizes that Apple uses and references in their design guidelines?

Tags: website-design, responsive-design, human-interface-guideline, apple

Does someone know, What are the specific dimensions (primarily width) of the breakpoint sizes that Apple uses and references in their design guidelines, name as the XS, SM.... XXL?

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/typography

Comment: You should edit [your existing question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/148696/know-the-dimensions-width-mainly-of-different-breakpoints-of-apple-devices-men) to get it re-opened instead of asking the same question again.

Comment: Why not ask Apple? They should know, and they should have an interest in you knowing.

Answer (score 1):

Those are not breakpoint sizes—they are dynamic type sizes that the user configures in their settings. Large is the default, but users can choose to render type sizes anywhere from x-small to xxx-large.

The Apple guidelines don't reference breakpoints (after all, most of their design is for native experiences), but their [page on layout](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/layout#Device-screen-sizes-and-orientations) has information that's closest to that.

Comment: Thanks Chloe for your answer here!